# Any new website I create does not work - I think I installed packages on the local user, before I figured out virtualenvs

Tags: pythonanywhere

My first flask app worked just fine, including the sql.
Then on later on I pip installed some module but this was not on the `virtualenv`, but rather the base user profile
Any new web app I create now doesn't work, even if using a `virtualenv`.

This is my error log. When I tried to pip install `jinja2` in my `virtualenv`, it says it's installed. Then I tried to run it on the basic user profile outside of `myvirtualenv` and it's same.

> 2023-04-23 06:58:31,702: Error running WSGI application 2023-04-23
> 06:58:31,707: ImportError: cannot import name 'Markup' from 'jinja2'
> (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jinja2/**init**.py)
> 2023-04-23 06:58:31,708:   File
> "/var/www/test2-andrewklamerus_eu_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line
> 16, in  2023-04-23 06:58:31,708:     from flask_app import app
> as application  # noqa 2023-04-23 06:58:31,708:  2023-04-23
> 06:58:31,708:   File "/home/andrewklamerus/flask4/flask_app.py", line
> 4, in  2023-04-23 06:58:31,708:     from flask import Flask
> 2023-04-23 06:58:31,708:  2023-04-23 06:58:31,708:   File
> "/home/andrewklamerus/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/**init**.py",
> line 19, in  2023-04-23 06:58:31,708:     from jinja2 import
> Markup, escape

The code in the web app is still just "Hello world" so this is more of a setup issue. I tried `myvirtualenv` but that didn't help.

I know there's [this](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError), but as much as I've found other tutorials helpful, I'm not sure what to do now.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like you may have a version of jinja2 installed that is not compatible with the version of Flask that you're using. You appear to be using the pre-installed jinja2 and Flask that you have installed yourself. Check the documentation for the version of Flask that you have installed and make sure that you are using a version of jinja2 that is compatible.